# How can i get current div id which are having same class created daynmically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

  <div class="ratestar" id="abc" >

                            <input type="radio" name="example"  class="rating" value="1" />
                            <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="2" />
                            <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="3" />
                            <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="4" />
                            <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="5" />
                         </div>}
```

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       // $('.ratestar').rating();

       $('.ratestar').rating(function (vote, event) {
           //alert(vote);
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           alert(id);
           // write your ajax code here
           $.ajax({

               url: '@Url.Action("RequestQuoteAll_ajax", "Engineer")',
               data: { CompanyID: ComapnyID },
               type: 'POST',
               success: function (data) {

                   data;
               }
           });
           // For example;
           // $.get(document.URL, {vote: vote});
       });

   });
</script>
```

---

I have 6 radio button with same class and I am unable to get current div id when the loop runs multiple times.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. You want to iterate through a list of divs which have the same class (generated dynamicaly) and you want to do something with each of these? And I see that you in your code try to get the id of the div, but the divs don't have an id.

Comment: oh line is miss <div class="rate_star" id="@item.companyID">

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--KEEP DYNAMIC ID -->   
<div class="ratestar" id="<Here_Dynamic_Id>" >
// YOU WILL GET THE DYNAMIC ID OF ONLY THAT DIV WHICH WILL BE CLICKED
var strCurrentDivId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: This line of only get id of first div but but my code generate number of divs dynamically by foreach loop and i am assigning dynamically id to every div...:(

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. This will take you to the parent div and give the id

```
var id = $(this).closest('div.ratestar').attr('id');
       alert(id);
```